# MySQL stored procedure; multi statment procedure, throws error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
UPDATE Decks 
JOIN Amount ON amount.DeckName = decks.DeckName 
SET decks.DeckTotal = Decks.DeckTotal - Decks.DeckTotal
WHERE Amount.AmountName = @aName;

UPDATE Types t1
JOIN Cards ON cards.TypeName = t1.TypeName 
JOIN Amount ON amount.CardName = Cards.CardName
SET t1.TypeTotal = t1.TypeTotal - Amount.Amount
WHERE Amount.CardName = @aName;

DELETE * 
FROM Amount 
WHERE CardName = @aName;
```

The above is throwing an error when I try and put it into a stored procedure using phpMyAdmin. It says there is an error in my syntax as soon as the second statement begins.

[Attached is a screenshot of the erroer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qCdR.png)

Comment: Did you set the variable using `phpmyadmin` stored procedure panel?

Comment: I did, Shaharyar. It is set, as are its fields. I just double checked it there.

Comment: Now just add `BEGIN` at the start of your procedure and `END` at the end of procedure and try again.

Comment: No luck. I have been trying to enter it using the phpmyadmin GUI. I will try enter it as a statement and check in a min.

Comment: using a statement says syntax error, I do it using UI al the time. Can you add an screenshot while setting it up?

Comment: Hey I have updated my comment to include a link to the photo I uploaded. I has the error message attached aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `*` from your delete query..Then it will work fine

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `sp_test`()
Begin
      UPDATE Decks 
      JOIN Amount ON amount.DeckName = decks.DeckName 
      SET decks.DeckTotal = Decks.DeckTotal - Decks.DeckTotal
      WHERE Amount.AmountName =1;

      UPDATE Types t1
      JOIN Cards ON cards.TypeName = t1.TypeName 
      JOIN Amount ON amount.CardName = Cards.CardName
      SET t1.TypeTotal = t1.TypeTotal - Amount.Amount
      WHERE Amount.CardName = @aName;

      DELETE 
      FROM Amount 
      WHERE CardName = @aName;
 end
```

Comment: Jordan you beautiful person, thank you so much! Have a wonderful day. May the blessings of a thousand Lilly Drops light your path to eternal glory!

Comment: And Shaharyar, thank you also. It is so nice of ye to help and give yer time. I cant convey how much yer interaction has helped.